# C++ Eclipse ld: library not found for -l

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++, libraries

I have a main project and a Library project.  When I try to build in Eclipse I keep getting this error:

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/hello/Hello.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I"/Users/pdl/Development/HelloWorld/Namer/src/namer" 
-include"/Users/pdl/Development/HelloWorld/Namer/src/namer/World.h" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c 
-fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/hello/Hello.d" -MT"src/hello/Hello.d" -o "src/hello/Hello.o" "../src/hello/Hello.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/hello/Hello.cpp

Building target: Hello
Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
g++ -L"/Users/pdl/Development/HelloWorld/Namer" -o "Hello"  ./src/hello/Hello.o 
-l"/Users/pdl/Development/HelloWorld/Namer/src/namer/World.h"
ld: library not found for -l/Users/pdl/Development/HelloWorld/Namer/src/namer/World.h
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Hello] Error 1
```

I'm not trying to debug.  I'm just trying to build.

Thank you, in advance.

---

## Here is my code:

Hello is my main project and Namer is my library.

In my Hello project, I have a folder structure like this:
src -> hello

**Hello.cpp:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "World.h"

int main() {
  printf("Hello %s\n", getWorld().c_str());
  return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.6)
project(Hello)
find_package(Namer REQUIRED)
include_directories("${Namer_INCLUDE-DIRS}")
add_executable(hello main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hello ${Namer_LIBRARIES})
```

**FindNamer.cmake**

```
find_path(Namer_INCLUDE_DIRS World.h /usr/include "$ENV{NAMER_ROOT}")

find_library(Namer_LIBRARIES namer /usr/lib "$ENV{NAMER_ROOT}")

set(Namer_FOUND TRUE)

if (NOT Namer_INCLUDE_DIRS)
    set(Namer_FOUND FALSE)
endif (NOT Namer_INCLUDE_DIRS)

if (NOT Namer_LIBRARIES)
    set(Namer_FOUND FALSE)
endif (NOT Namer_LIBRARIES)
```

In my Namer project, I have a folder structure like this:
src -> namer

**World.cpp:**

```
#include "World.h"

std::string getWorld() { return "Earth"; }

int main() {
  printf("We are in Namer %s\n", getWorld().c_str());
  return 0;
}
```

**World.h:**

```
#include <string>

std::string getWorld();
```

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.6)
project(Namer)
include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
add_library(namer World.cpp World.h)
```

Comment: It looks like you may have a problem with your Makefile.  It is trying to link against a header file.  Can you post the contents of your Makefile?

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are building into "src/hello/Hello.o" but do wrong search. `-l"/Users/pdl/Development/HelloWorld/Namer/src/namer/World.h"` should be library not a header in Linker command. Check your project settings.

Comment: I think you are correct but I'm trying to learn CMake and it's really hard.  So I'll post the code.